# Linux: Kill process on specific port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, operating-systems

How to kill a process if its port is known? For example if a process is running at port `12345` then how it can be terminated in linux/ubuntu.

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
sudo netstat -tupln
```

to show what is listening on what port. You should see something similar to this (I've simplified the output somewhat).

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2472/apache2
```

That fourth column (0.0.0.0:80 in my example) will show you the port number (80 here) and the final column (2472/apache2) will show you the PID (2472).

You can then issue

```
sudo kill -15 PID
```

where PID is the PID we found with the previous command. This will send SIGTERM to the process. If that fails, you may need to

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

but that is generally a less friendly way to kill process. For more info, you should checkout

```
man kill
```

Comment: I've been searching for a simple solution. This is it. It should be accepted. Thanks for the great response.

Answer (score 1):

1. list all listening port:

   > netstat -antu
2. take the correspondent one, let's say 80 and kill it using this:

   > kill -9 $( lsof -i:80 -t )